# Delete files rather than putting to trash in Jupyter Notebook in a Docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter

I am running Jupyter Notebook in a Docker container. There is the following problem - when I delete a file in Jupyter Notebook it is being put to trash rather than deleted. Because of it, the size of a container is getting really big. Is it possible to configure Jupyter Notebook or a container to delete files instead of putting them to trash?

Comment: I don't know whether there's any way to set that in Jupyter or not(if it's possible , that's the ultimate solution), but you can write a crontab rule to empty the trash directory for example every 10 minutes.You can run ```sudo crontab -e```,then add this rule ```10 * * * * rm -rf ./Trash-1000```.Replace **./Trash-1000** with whatever the name of the trash directory is.And the fields are **minute** , **hour** , **day of the month** , **month of the year** , **day of the week** respectively.